# django - Hide the objects if all its related objects are hidden

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

How to hide the `object` if all its related `objects` are hidden.

Please let me explain a little more. Suppose, a user has four messages in one thread (Thread_1). And he deletes/hides all the messages from that thread. So now there's no message in the thread (Thread_1). How do I hide that thread (Thread_1) which has no messages to show in the template (whose messages are all hidden).

models.py

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    body = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class HideMessage(models.Model):
    message = models.ForeignKey(Message)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Any help will be grateful. Thank you!

**Edit:**

html:

```
    <div id="inbox">
        <div id="threads">
            {% for thread in all_threads %}
                <div class="thread">
                    <a href="/message/get/{{thread.id}}/">
                    <p>{{thread.id}}
                    {% for user in thread.user.all %}
                        {{user.username}},
                    {% endfor %}
                    </p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <hr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div id="conversation">
            {% for message in messages %}
                {% if message|is_hidden:user %}
                    <div class="messages">
                        <p>{{message.body}}</p>
                        <p>{{message.sent_date}}</p>
                        <p>-{{message.user}}</p>
                    <hr>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="clear_left"></div>
    </div>
```

**Edit:**

```
@login_required
def home(request):
    user = request.user

    # Get all the threads of that user
    threads = user.thread_set.all()

    # Order the threads by which thread recieved the latest message.
    order_threads_message = threads.annotate(max_sent_date=Max('message__sent_date')).order_by('-max_sent_date')

    # Get the recent thread
    recent_thread = order_threads_message[0]

    # Get the message of the recent thread
    recent_thread_messages = recent_thread.message_set.all()

    return render(request, 'base.html', {'all_threads':order_threads_message, 'messages':recent_thread_messages})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL, you may do it in one shot:

```
queryset = Thread.objects.extra(select={
    'msg_count': 'select count(*) from appname_message where appname_message.thread_id=appname_thread.id',
    'hidden_count': 'select count(*) from appname_hidemessage where appname_message.thread_id=appname_thread.id',
}, where=[
    'msg_count > hidden_count',
])
```

This will only select threads that have more *messages* than *hidemessages*. Note: replace all occurrences of **appname** with the actual app name.

I must note however, that's a really strange modelling. Wouldn't a boolean flag suffice?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, the hide message should be 0? I am sorry I didnt get you. Will you please elaborate a little more. And could you please tell me where you think the boolean field must be?